# mover un archivo a una carpeta en el servidor move_uploaded_file

Tags: php

Estoy mandando un archivo .doc a mi archivo subiir_Archivo.php  los parametros si llegan pero cuando quiero mover la el archivo a una carpeta no hace nada.

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
require_once '../mail/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
/*$prueba = new Cliente();
$prueba->listar();*/

//include_once("../conexion/conexion.php");
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","****");
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$celular = $_POST['celular'];
$comentario = $_POST['comentario'];

$directorio="../csv/";
$nombreArchvio=$_FILES['csv']['name'];

echo $directorio.'  '.$nombreArchvio;
 
move_uploaded_file($directorio,$nombreArchvio);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
 
// Perform a query, check for error
if (!mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `csv`(`nombre`, `email`, `celular`, `csv`, `comentario`) VALUES ('$nombre','$email','$celular','$nombreArchvio','$comentario')"))
{
  echo 'llego';
echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leer [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file.php) de `move_uploaded_file($source, $destination)`

Tienes que capturar el archivo físico de origen como `$_FILES[foo]['tmp_name']` y `$destination` debe tener el nombre completo del archivo de destino, ya sea usando el original, `['name']`, u otro personalizado.

```
$file_src = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];
$nombreArchvio = $_FILES['csv']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($file_src, $directorio . $nombreArchvio);
```

Comment: muchas gracias en localhost si funciona pero en el servidor de producción no me lo guarda

Comment: @CarlosEnriqueGilGil Muy probablemente sea tema de permisos de escritura en el directorio de destino de IIS o Linux. El directorio de `csv` ponle permisos de escritura para todos los usuarios o 777 para hacer pruebas.

Comment: si tuviste razon gracias