# php mover archivo

Tags: php, funciones, archivo

estoy teniendo un problema con el siguiente codigo:

```
<form action="uploadImage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Y en uploadImage.php :

```
<?php
$target_dir = "assests/Pictures/Profile/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}
?>
```

Pero cuando ejecuto el codigo, no me tira ningun error y cuando voy a la carpeta, que existe, no encuentro el archivo. Cual puede ser el problema?

Gracias!

Comment: Falta mover el archivo de la carpeta temporal a `$target_dir`, con [`move_uploaded_file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Mover un archivo a una carpeta en el servidor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/374932/80870) Verifica, además, los permisos del directorio de destino.

Answer (score 0):

```
                  <form action="destino.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                       <label for="imagen">Imagen:</label> 
                       <input  id="file" name="archivo[]" size="30" type="file" />
                       <input type="submit" value="Subir foto" />
                     </form>
```

.

```
#definimos la carpeta destino
    $carpetaDestino="../images/";
    $nombre=$_FILES['archivo']['name'];
 
# si hay algun archivo que subir
if(isset($_FILES["archivo"]) && $nombre[0])
{

    # recorremos todos los arhivos que se han subido
    for($i=0;$i<count($nombre);$i++)
    {

        # si es un formato de imagen
        if($_FILES["archivo"]["type"][$i]=="image/jpeg" || $_FILES["archivo"]["type"][$i]=="image/pjpeg" || $_FILES["archivo"]["type"][$i]=="image/gif" || $_FILES["archivo"]["type"][$i]=="image/png")
        {

            # si exsite la carpeta o se ha creado
            if(file_exists($carpetaDestino) || @mkdir($carpetaDestino))
            {
                $origen=$_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"][$i];
                $destino=$carpetaDestino.$nombre[$i];

                # movemos el archivo
                if(@move_uploaded_file($origen, $destino))
                {
                    $con= $nombre[$i];
                }else{
                    echo "<br>No se ha podido mover el archivo: ".$nombre[$i];
                }
            }else{
                echo "<br>No se ha podido crear la carpeta: ".$carpetaDestino;
            }
        }else{
            echo "<br>".$nombre[$i]." - NO es imagen jpg, png o gif";
        }
    }
}else{
    echo "<br>No se ha subido ninguna imagen";
}
```

Espero que te pueda ayudar, saludos!